# How can I serve arbitrary request paths?

Tags: python, zope

How can I serve arbitrary paths zope.browserrsource does for @@ and ++resource++ URIs in Zope?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? The `@@` syntax is a shortcut for a longer `++namespace++` lookup; `++resource++` is a namespaced lookup, did you want to register another `++...++` url namespace?

Comment: Yes -- that is what I am looking for. I have been reading over zope.browserresource, but can not quite follow it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two adapters needed for this. One adapts the ZODB context one wishes to use and zope.publisher.interfaces.IRequest, while providing `zope.traversing.interfaces.ITraversable` (view). The second adapts the previous objects instantiated view and `zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserRequest`, while providing `zope.publisher.interfaces.IPublishTraverse` (traverser). I subclassed BrowserView for both adapters.

Inside the traverser, the publishTraverse method will be called successively for each URL part that is being traversed and returns a view for that URL part.